# Android How draw couple Rects in canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

I need draw couple Rects I saw only one Rect . How can I saw couple ?
I tried in couple way but I see only one Rect

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint=new Paint();
        paint.setARGB(255,0,0,0);
        canvas.drawRect(10,20,30,30,paint);
        canvas.drawRect(200,50,40,30,paint);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters for drawRect are left, top, right, bottom. In your second Rect left is greater than (right of) right and top is greater than (below) bottom. What do you expect this to draw?